# Getting UUID of a usb when ejecting using udev

Tags: python, udev

0
down vote
favorite
I am having a python script to get plugged in usb details. I am using udev library to manage the connected devices.

I want to get the device Id of the USB device when I remove it from system.

If I remove the device without unmounting, I am getting the device Id using device.get('ID_FS_UUID').

But If I remove the device after unmounting, then I am not getting the device Id using above code.I am getting value as None.

I have a udev monitor observer class to detect the addition and removal of usb device.

*from pyudev.glib import GUDevMonitorObserver as MonitorObserver

```
    def device_event(observer, action, device):
        if action == 'add':
            DeviceListener.deviceAdded(device)
        else:
            DeviceListener.deviceRemoved(device)*
```

based on the event it will call corresponding method.

```
def deviceRemoved(device):
print "REMOVED DEVICE IS="+device.get('ID_FS_UUID')
```

If I remove the device without unmounting, I am getting following output, REMOVED DEVICE IS=5F96-58D0

If I unmount and remove the device I am getting following output, REMOVED DEVICE IS=None

Please help me to find the device Id in the second case.

Thanks In advance...

Comment: There are a few standard commands, that will print the device ID: 1. `sudo parted -ls` and specifically for a particular device `sudo parted /dev/sdx print` where x is the device letter, for example `b`; 2. `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id` and specifically for a particular device `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep sdx$`, where x is the device letter, for example `b` -- If you unmount partitions of a device with `umount /dev/sdx?`, these commands work, but if you eject a device (and turn it off) it will not be seen and not identified. Maybe this is the problem (that you eject, not unmount).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here I am using UDEV library to get device UUID of plugged in device. I tried the commands you suggested but I need the UUID using udev.

Comment: What about the UUID that is listed by `sudo lsblk -f`or specifically `sudo lsblk -f /dev/sdx`; I have no experience of using the UDEV library, so let us hope that someone who knows will chip in a help you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, It is not possible to get such info from a live state tree like SYSFS. Those inf are cleared with clean umount.

Best way to me is to keep a copy of such info about the plugged devices, then check them when a device is unplugged.